# Monads on Set and their strength

Tags: category-theory

I've been told that "every monad on Set has an unique strength". Is that true? (I can't seem to prove it)

I did find a couple of hits googling, but they were mostly just statements without proofs. Can anyone post a link of a paper where this is proved (if it is in fact even correct)

PS: The uniqueness of the strength is what bothers me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course one can also check this directly. If $T$ is a monad on $\mathsf{Set}$, then the strength $X \times T(Y) \to T(X \times Y)$ has to take $(x,s)$ to the image of $T(x : Y \to X \times Y)$ under $s$. This follows from naturality w.r.t. $x : \star \to X$ and that $\star \times T(Y) \to T(\star \times Y)$ is required to be the canonical map.

Answer (score 2):

It is unique. See [here](http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/820/commutative-algebraic-theory/?Focus=29783#Comment_29783) for a description of the strength; for uniqueness, you use Kock's theorem that strengths for an endofunctor correspond bijectively with enrichments, and every functor is enriched over $\mathbf{Set}$ in a unique way. See also Proposition 3.3.2 [here](http://zll22.user.srcf.net/writing/algebraic-theories/20121121-Main.pdf).